# codeigniter conditional function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter as a framework.
Firstly, I use:

```
public function edit_ads_wait($id)
{
   $where["user"]=$this->session->userdata("userid");
   $where["id"]=$id;
   $where["state"]=2;
   $info=$this->base->get_where_row("advertisement",$where);
   if($info) // if $info isset
   {
        $where_cat["deleted"]=0;
        $data["info"]=$info;
        $data["category"]=$this->base->get_where("category",$where_cat,$order);
        $data["region"]=$this->base->get("region");
        $this->userskin->loadview("user/ads/edit_ads",$data);

   }else // if $info is not set
    {
        $this->clear_session();
    }
}
```

when i  execute edit_ads_wait function -where the $info isset- it also run clear_session() function and my session is cleared

the clear_session is

```
function clear_session()
{
     foreach ($this->session->all_userdata() as $key=>$val)
    {

          if(strlen($key)>=20)
          {  
            $this->session->unset_userdata($key);
          }
            //print_r($key);
    }
}
```

please help me...

Comment: Err.... try explaining that again?

Comment: excuseme whene i excute edit_ads_wait function in codeigniter and set value in $info variable but execute $this->clear_session(); and my session is lost

Comment: Make sure your `$info` is not `null, flase, empty`. Try `var_dump($info);`.

Comment: tanks alot i sure and check it but problem not fixed

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are using the function inside of the "view" not the "controller", if so

a quick fix : try to add `exit();` at the end of your `if` condition before the `else` .

or if your function inside your controller class make sure the class looks like that

ex : if the controller file name is `example.php` :

```
    <?php
       class Example extends CI_Controller {
        //your constructor
        function exmple() {
          parent::__construct();
       // you can load libraries and helpers here
        }

 // your other functions

      }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this:

```
  if $info is an array then:
      if(isset($info) && !empty($info)) 

  if $info is a single value then:
      if(isset($info) && $info != '')
```

Comment: thank you its true i try it but i dont know why when condition is true in hidden execute clear session()